# How do you create a list object from a dataframe based on a column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the following `df`, how could you create the desired output below? I'm specifically after a list of lists of tuples.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['ab_c_1.0.0','ab_c_1.0.1','ab_c_1.0.2','ab_c_1.1.0','ab_c_1.1.1','ab_c_1.2.0','ab_c_1.3.0','ab_c_1.3.1'],
                   'y':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'],
                   'z':['i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p']})
df
>>>
             x  y   z
0   ab_c_1.0.0  a   i
1   ab_c_1.0.1  b   j
2   ab_c_1.0.2  c   k
3   ab_c_1.1.0  d   l
4   ab_c_1.1.1  e   m
5   ab_c_1.2.0  f   n
6   ab_c_1.3.0  g   o
7   ab_c_1.3.1  h   p
```

Desired output:

```
[[('a', 'i'), ('b', 'j'), ('c', 'k')],
 [('d', 'l'), ('e', 'm')],
 [('f', 'n')],
 [('g', 'o'), ('h', 'p')]]
```

I have so far thought that I could combine something like this to get, so to speak, keys:

```
for a in df['x']:
    if a.endswith('.0'):
```

with this:

```
df.values.tolist()
```

however, it's quite obviously inefficient to be iterating multiple times and through multiple objects. The main problem is that I can't slice the `df` by any constant other than checking whether the last digit of string in the `x` column is `0`, so I can't use a rolling window or something like this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the list values depends on `x` column? If not, we can do something like this: `df[['y', 'z']].values.tolist()`

Comment: The list values depend on the `x` column for ordering, as you can see in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
out = [list(zip(g['y'], g['z'])) for k, g in
       df.groupby(df['x'].str.endswith('0').cumsum())]
```

Variant to consider the leading part of `x` as grouper, excluding the last digit:

```
out = [list(zip(g['y'], g['z'])) for k, g in
       df.groupby(df['x'].str.extract(r'(.*).\d', expand=False))]
```

Output:

```
[[('a', 'i'), ('b', 'j'), ('c', 'k')],
 [('d', 'l'), ('e', 'm')],
 [('f', 'n')],
 [('g', 'o'), ('h', 'p')]]
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks. It has also occurred to me that it could be a problem if the counts of the last digit in the strings in column `x` would range from say 0-100. Am I right in thinking that adjusting to `.endswith('.0')` in the first example would counter this issue? Could the regex in the second solution also be similarly adjusted in line with this? Don't edit your answer, as you've answered my original question, however you've made me think ahead to further problems that may arise outside of my toy problem.

Comment: If you want to restart every time the number ends with `.0` then `.endswith('.0')` is a good option. The regex uses a different logic, it considers the left part of the string and thus is independent of the order of the rows or the presence of a `0`

Comment: For my current problem, `.endswith('.0')` is suitable in every case.

Answer (score 1):

I would first find the indexes on column x where the zeros begin.

```
left = 0 
right = 1
slices = []
column_x = df['x']
while right < len(df):
    if column_x[right][-1] == '0':
        slices.append((left, right))
        left = right 
    right += 1
slices.append((left, right))
```

my slices array shows these indexes

```
[(0, 3), (3, 5), (5, 6), (6, 8)]
```

Then I would loop through all the slices and then loop through the range of the slices.

```
outer_list = []
for slice in slices:
    inner_list = []
    for index in range(slice[0], slice[1]):
        inner_list.append((df.iloc[index, 1], df.iloc[index, 2]))
    outer_list.append(inner_list)

print(outer_list)
[[('a', 'i'), ('b', 'j'), ('c', 'k')],
 [('d', 'l'), ('e', 'm')],
 [('f', 'n')],
 [('g', 'o'), ('h', 'p')]]
```

and you would get the desired outcome in the outer_list list

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:

```python
res = ( df
    .assign(x=df.x.str.extract(r'[^.]*\.([^.]*)')).set_index('x')
    .apply(tuple, axis=1).groupby('x').agg(list).tolist() )
```

Output:

```
[[('a', 'i'), ('b', 'j'), ('c', 'k')], [('d', 'l'), ('e', 'm')], [('f', 'n')], [('g', 'o'), ('h', 'p')]]
```

Note that the pattern argument passed to extract() is just an example and can be adjusted to get whichever component of column `x` is common to all rows whose tuples should be grouped together in the result. (The pattern I have used extracts the second substring in the dot-separated string value in column `x`.)